# Creating a Pylons Thread with Access to app_globals

Tags: python, multithreading, pylons, wsgi

I'd like to create a process that runs in the background of my pylons environment, unbound to client requests, with access to the pylons `app_globals` object. The general purpose of the process is to check client sessions for expiration and perform some post-expiration analysis.

Is this possible? I've tried creating a thread in the `config/environment.py` file but when I try to access properties of `app_globals` I get the following error:

```
TypeError: No object (name: app_globals) has been registered for this thread
```

Thanks in advance,
Will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object you are trying to access is [StackedObjectProxy](http://pythonpaste.org/modules/registry.html) registered by pylons for every request, for the serving thread.

If you only intend to read it, it is safe to use the one in config:

```
config.get('pylons.app_globals') or config.get('pylons.g')
```

Comment: This worked for me (pylons 0.9.7), but `pylons.app_globals._push_object(config['pylons.app_globals'])` did not. Perhaps I was using it incorrectly.

Comment: My solution for newer version of Pylons.

Answer (score 3):

You need register app_globals (in pylons app_globals registerd per request):

```
pylons.app_globals._push_object(config['pylons.app_globals'])
```

Comment: This worked for me, fyi. The accepted answer did not. Thanks.